# Let User Crop Photo in iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, image-processing, uiimage

There are several questions (and answers) concerning cropping of images/photos within an iPhone app.

But I couldn't find an answer covering the common task of giving the user a rectangle which can be resized with a pinch gesture to letting him resize the area to cut.

You can find this functionality in many apps (Instagram, Twitter, etc...) most likely to cut a user photo to the right proportions. So I guess there are many people with the same problem.

Does anyone have code or tutorials to show how this task can be done?

Comment: Hello. I have stucked to implement an ImageCropper to create it with 4:3 ratio based on width. [This is](http://ge.tt/4M9vgde1/v/0?c) what i have tried. But, no such output i got. Can you check this and tell me any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try Below links for example project :

https://github.com/iosdeveloper/ImageCropper

https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper

https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController

Comment: A combination of BJImageCropper and SSPhotoCropperViewController would be awsome! But both projects are good starting points.

Answer (score 7):

I made this one which combines elements from both mentioned.

https://github.com/nicholjs/BFCropInterface

Comment: Awesome example ...Thanx a lot for this . I have been trying to get this from long days.

Comment: you can add two crop ?

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/loveyiren208/XWEditPhotoDemo

try this one. I only found some project without ARC. So I decided to write a new one. It is similar with many applications when you change your profile photo.

Answer (score 3):

Try out this project: [ardalahmet / SSPhotoCropperViewController](https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController)