# Get original but cropped Co-ordinates of image in iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimage

I have two images. One is the original (let's say it's 830 x 1222 pixels. The other is a cropped image (let's say 300 x 300 pixels) takend from the original. Cropped image is as per the ratio of the Green rectangle shown in to the sample image below.

[image]
[image]

What I'm looking for is a way using objective C (iOS) to look at both images and find the coordinates of the cropped image within the original.

Hope that makes sense? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you cropping the photo within the app?

Comment: Yes I am going to make one application. which will offer user to set the x,y,width & height as per his/her wish. That portion will be cropped & its co-ordinates from original Image I need to identify.

Comment: then the frame you are putting to show a green foreground is already have the frame of image you want to crop why you are not using that frame?

Comment: Please use the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205946/let-user-crop-photo-in-ios-app

Comment: Yes, what I was getting at is if you are cropping the image in the app then you already know the frame as you are using it to crop. Instead of cropping the image and forgetting the frame, store the frame rect that you used.

Comment: Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/users/1603461/ieinstein and http://stackoverflow.com/users/421018/fogmeister