# how to remove the part of image except highlighting part in ios

Tags: ios

hi i have done getting image from Gallery or camera.and i have button when i click that button  getting image again from gallery or camera in which when i touch some part that is highlighting that should be only display in to anotherView.remaing part should be removed.please anybody assist me how to do this.help is appreciated. i written code this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
self.slider.hidden=NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];   //lastTouch is CGPoint  declared globally
}
//#pragma mark - Touch moved mehotd
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view1];    //currentTouch is CGPoint declared globally
CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view1.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[imageView1.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view1.frame.size.width, self.view1.frame.size.height)];
//canvasView is your UIImageView  object declared globally
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, slider.value);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
imageView1.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view1];
}
//#pragma mark - Touch end mehotd
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view1];
}
```

but it is erasing selected Area.but i don't want to erase the selected Area(highlight).unselected part should be erased .i tried a lot please any body reply me how to do this.help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question sounds good. I think somebody already give answer earlier like same query.

Please have a look following

[Let User Crop Photo in iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205946/let-user-crop-photo-in-ios-app)

i hope will help you. All the best!! :)